# Proving an equality of two sums using induction for $n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: summation, induction

I stumbled across an exercise about induction that I can't come around to find a solution for.

I have to prove for all natural numbers that

$$ \sum_{k=n}^{2n}{k} = 3\sum_{l=0}^{n}{l}$$

I started the proof as usual by proving that the equality is at least true for $n_0$.
So for $n=1$ I got 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{2}{k} = 3\sum_{l=0}^{1}{l} \Rightarrow$$
$$ 1+2=3(0+1) \Rightarrow 3=3 $$ and therefore the statement is true for $n_0=1$ 
Now with the requirement that the equality is true for $n \in \mathbb N$,
I assume that the equality is also true for $n+1$ which means:
$$\color{red}{\sum_{k=n}^{2n+1}{k}} = 3\sum_{l=0}^{n+1}{l} \space$$ 
With this assumption I have to execute the inductive step which is where I encounter my problem. 
I have to prove that if the statement holds for $n$ then it also holds for $n+1$. 
What I get is:
$$\sum_{k=n}^{2(n+1)}{k} = 3\sum_{l=0}^{n+1}{l} \Rightarrow$$ 
$$\sum_{k=n}^{2n}{k}+2(n+1) = 3\sum_{l=0}^{n}{l}+3(n+1) \Rightarrow$$
$$\sum_{k=n}^{2n}{k} = 3\sum_{l=0}^{n}{l}+(n+1)$$
According to my understanding the proof should end with:
$$\sum_{k=n}^{2n}{k} = 3\sum_{l=0}^{n}{l}$$ which of course is the starting equality.Unfortunately I don't end up with it, and I can't understand why.
Any insight on the particular problem, or a way to approach induction problems with an equality between sums would be appreciated.

Comment: I have colored the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that when you increase $n$ by $1$ on the LHS, you add the terms $2n+1$ and $2n+2$, and subtract the term $n$, leading to a total increase of $3n+3$. Note that increasing $n$ by $1$ on the RHS adds the term $3n+3$. The induction is straightforward from here.

The mistake you made is that $\sum \limits_{k=n}^{2n+1}$ should be $\sum \limits_{k=n+1}^{2n+2}$; your proof would have worked if you did this.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how exactly the proof concludes, because when I use the index shift formula $ \sum_{n=s}^{t}{f(n)} = \sum_{n=s+p}^{t+p}{f(n-p) }$ for $p=-1$ I get $ \sum_{k=n+1}^{2(n+1)}{k} = \sum_{k=n}^{2n+1}{k+1}$ which equals  $ \sum_{k=n}^{2n}{k} +2n+2$ Instead of  $ \sum_{k=n}^{2n}{k} +3n+3$ that I think I need.

Comment: @KonstantinosZafeiris When you got to $\sum_{k=n}^{2n+1} (k+1)$, you should have taken out $2n+2$ as the greatest term, as well as $n+1$ to turn $k+1$ into $k$.

Answer (score 1):

This $$\sum_{k=n}^{2n+1}{k} $$   should be $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+2}{k} $$

Comment: I am obviously a much less experienced member than you are, but shouldn't this be a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: @Aqua So I should also change the index of summation. I understand my mistake now, I just thought that because it's an index it wouldn't be affected. By it makes sense now since that '+1' is the (n+1) I am missing

Comment: Glad I could help